# Nouislider reactjs set value

Tags: reactjs, nouislider

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-react 
can't insert value into slider

```
 class KeyboardSlider extends React.Component {
  state = { ref: null };

  changeByRef = () => {
    const { ref } = this.state;
    if (ref && ref.noUiSlider) {
      ref.noUiSlider.set(20);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeByRef}>Change with ref</button>
        <Nouislider
          instanceRef={instance => {
            if (instance && !ref) {
              this.setState({ ref: instance });
            }
          }}
          start={0}
          range={{
            min: 0,
            max: 100
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this code does not work gives an error
Line 665:  'ref' is not defined  no-undef
....................................................................................................

Comment: I know this is old but did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this code i just refactor you are using the ref in wrong way.

you can also use input and change the value by updating the start prop on Slider.

```js
 class KeyboardSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.CreateRef();
  }

  changeByRef = () => {
    
    if (this.ref && this.ref.noUiSlider) {
      this.ref.noUiSlider.set(20);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeByRef}>Change with ref</button>
        <Nouislider
          instanceRef={instance => {
            if (instance && !ref) {
              this.setState({ ref: instance });
            }
          }}
          start={0}
          range={{
            min: 0,
            max: 100
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: The original is following the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nouislider-react#using-with-ref

Which doesn't work (give 'ref' undefined error).

Your answer also gives a 'ref' undefined error. Both ways didn't work for me